# Cannot get the background color to change on mouseover

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-class

I'm struggling with getting a section background color to change on mouse over. I'm trying to turn the entire section into a link. Right now, only the elements inside the section become links, not the block itself.

If I remove the `<section>` prior to the `<a>` the whole block becomes a link but the background sill does not change on mouse-over. I have an identical scenario in a menu and it works, so I'm a little confused here. I'm also wondering why only the elements turn into links withing a section and it does the opposite in my sub menu. Section code below:

```css
.ch-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  color: $ch-section-text;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $body-1px-line;
}
.ch-section a {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ch-section a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ch-section a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: $sn-list-link-active;
}
```

```html
<section class="ch-section">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="ch-section-selected not"></span>
    <img class="ch-section-image" src="assets/images/profileimg2.png" alt="img">
    <span class="ch-section-user">
      <span class="ch-section-status online"></span>
      <span class="ch-section-name">Lindset T. Peters</span>
      <span class="ch-section-location">Location, Province</span>
    </span>
    <time class="ch-section-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-sent ch-section-message"></i>
    <span class="ch-section-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: This seems to work for me.  Perhaps you are having a browser compatibility issue.  Or perhaps you need to clarify what your desired goal/issue is?  In any event, the hover state works for me in Chrome.  Additionally, the "...why elements turn into links..." part is another question by itself and should possibly be asked separately.

Comment: What background?
Your css doesn't contain any `background` commands

Comment: If it's the section, you can add `section:hover {background: your image or color here }`

Comment: @Roysh On hover the background should turn to yellow as long as it's not set to active.

Comment: This also seems to work for me. Here's a working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1sw7e0q/)

Comment: @Joshua I've tested it in both the latest chrome and Firefox.

Comment: so how about `section:hover {background: yellow; }`
and how do you know if it's active?

Comment: @Roysh if its active it has an active class.

Comment: Then `section:not(.active):hover {background: yellow; }`

Comment: @Roysh, I added a hover state to the section itself and that works fine.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else who assisted with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm struggling with getting a section background color to change on
>   mouse over. I'm trying to turn the entire section into a link. Right
>   now, only the elements inside the section become links, not the block
>   itself.
>
> If I remove the  prior to the  the whole block becomes a
>   link but the background sill does not change on mouse-over.

It is because you have `a` as child of the `section`, so make it parent (as I did it in a previous question you had).

```css
.ch-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 140px;
  max-height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  color: $ch-section-text;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $body-1px-line;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a .ch-section {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}
a.active .ch-section {
  font-weight: bold;
}
a:hover:not(.active) .ch-section {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: $sn-list-link-active;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <section class="ch-section">

    <span class="ch-section-selected not"></span>
    <img class="ch-section-image" src="assets/images/profileimg2.png" alt="img">
    <span class="ch-section-user">
      <span class="ch-section-status online"></span>
    <span class="ch-section-name">Lindset T. Peters</span>
    <span class="ch-section-location">Location, Province</span>
    </span>
    <time class="ch-section-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-sent ch-section-message"></i>
    <span class="ch-section-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>

  </section>
</a>
```

Comment: Without actually checking the specs., it's *sounds* pretty hacky to have an anchor element as a parent to a `<section>` element. I'm not saying the answer is wrong, but perhaps the CSS/HTML structure of the OP needs to be more heavily revised (in an ideal world.....) ?

Comment: @Martin If there is a more correct way of doing it I'd like to know, I'm quire new to CSS/HTML. Cheers

Comment: @dippas What sort of browser compatibility issues are there with this method?

Comment: I don't see any, since IE9 can handle HTML5, and this is not a huge feature or some sort.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem here is that you haven't set the height of your `a` tag. However when setting the `a` tag height to 100%, you will notice it still won't work. This is because the `section` has no fixed height specified. Instead you specified both `min-height` and `max-height` to be the same height, which doesn't really make sense. If instead you specify `height:140px`, it will work as expected:

```css
.ch-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 140px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.ch-section a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.ch-section a.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ch-section a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="ch-section">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="ch-section-selected not"></span>
    <img class="ch-section-image" src="assets/images/profileimg2.png" alt="img">
    <span class="ch-section-user">
      <span class="ch-section-status online"></span>
      <span class="ch-section-name">Lindset T. Peters</span>
      <span class="ch-section-location">Location, Province</span>
    </span>
    <time class="ch-section-date">8:48 AM</time>
    <i class="fa fa-e1-message-sent ch-section-message"></i>
    <span class="ch-section-snippet">Hey, it was really good to see you over the weekend, I look forward to...</span>
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: This also solved my issue. On closer examination of my sub navigation code, there is padding on that, which must be why that works.